Using PAT to authenticate against AzureDevops Git in AzApi Terraform Provider
I am trying to use the AzApi Terraform Provider to install fluxcd on a k8s cluster running on Azure Cloud.
Fluxcd should then look for changes in a AzureDevops Git Repo.
In the AzApi Terraform Flux Documentation it gives me the option to set a bunch of authentication related parameters for the Git Repo, but no Personal Access Token (PAT) which is the only way I can authenticate against the AzureDevops Git Repo.
It offers httpsCACert, but I do not know how to create one for my DevOps Git Repo.
It offers localAuthRef to define a "Name of a local secret on the Kubernetes cluster to use as the authentication secret" but I do not know what that means.
